# ¿Como graficar un rombo compuesto por cuatro cuadrados solo con css?

Tags: css, html5, css3

tengo un solo rombo bueno es un cuadrado solo que lo rote, solo tengo esto en html:

```css
.rombo-seguridad{
 margin:20px;
 width: 150px;
 height: 150px;      
 border: 1px solid black;
 border-top:75px solid red;
    border-right:75px solid blue;
    border-bottom:75px solid yellow;
 border-left:75px solid white;    
 -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);     
 -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);     
 -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);     
 -o-transform: rotate(45deg);     
 transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="rombo-seguridad"> </div>
```

quisiera que los triángulos formados dentro del rombo fueran cuadrados solo que no se como hacerlo.

Comment: Hola, ¿podrías agregar mas información de como quieres que se vea? si es posible una imagen por ejemplo.

Comment: Quieres que el rombo esté relleno con el color correspondiente en cada cara?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes colocar 4 divs cuadrados con los colores de fondo dentro del div principal y luego rotarlo de la siguiente forma:

```css
.rombo-seguridad{
    margin:20px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;      
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);     
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);     
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);     
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);     
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.rombo{
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  position: absolute;
}

.red{
  background-color: red;
}
.blue{
  background-color: blue;
  top: 75px;
}
.green{
  background-color: green;
  left: 75px;
}
.yellow{
  background-color: yellow;
  top: 75px;
  left: 75px;
}
```

```html
<div class="rombo-seguridad"> 

  <div class="rombo red"> </div>
  <div class="rombo blue"> </div>
  <div class="rombo green"> </div>
  <div class="rombo yellow"> </div>
</div>
```

Para que se los cuadrados se mantengan en sus posiciones puedes usar `position: absolute;` y para acomodar su posición `top` y `left`.

Si deseas agregar un centro blanco como en el código de la pregunta, puedes agregar un div con fondo `white` en medio del rombo según sus medidas:

```css
.rombo-seguridad{
    margin:20px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;      
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);     
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);     
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);     
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);     
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.rombo{
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  position: absolute;
}

.red{
  background-color: red;
}
.blue{
  background-color: blue;
  top: 75px;
}
.green{
  background-color: green;
  left: 75px;
}
.yellow{
  background-color: yellow;
  top: 75px;
  left: 75px;
}
.white{
  background-color: white;
  top: 37px;
  left: 37px;
}
```

```html
<div class="rombo-seguridad"> 

  <div class="rombo red"> </div>
  <div class="rombo blue"> </div>
  <div class="rombo green"> </div>
  <div class="rombo yellow"> </div>
  <div class="rombo white"> </div>
</div>
```

Espero te sea de ayuda, saludos.

Comment: Excelente!! muchas gracias era justo a lo que quería llegar

Comment: @Davidrnk, de nada, que tengas buen día.